# Receiving push notifications using adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to receive push notifications on my device, using the below adb shell command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -c com.xxxx.android -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -e data "Data"
```

But I am not receiving any push messages or errors.

This is the output I get:

```
Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.myapp] (has extras) } Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is the basic use of **adb broadcast** command:

```
adb shell am broadcast
-a <INTENT_NAME>
-n <PACKAGE_NAME>/<RECEIVER_NAME>
[--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>]
[--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE>]
[--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE>]
[--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>]
[--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>]
[--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE>]
[--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
[--e*a <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_*_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_*_VALUE...]]
```

And you can find the **RECEIVER_NAME** in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<receiver
    android:name="foo.bar.SomeBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="xyz.abc" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Example command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -n <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>/<YOUR_RECEIVER_NAME> --es "<EXTRA_KEY>" "<EXTRA_VALUE>"
```

Comment: Remove android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" for testing. Having that parameter there, states we only want messages coming from activities having the SEND permission - which the command line tool doesn't have.

Comment: I always get this: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad component name: com.android.phone`

Answer (score 1):

Use should use key **-n** instead **-c**.

Key -c is category key.

```
    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
```

Use this command, just change your package name:

```
 adb shell am broadcast -n com.myapp -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -e key "data"
```