# Is There an adb/shell command to list the items on the android's notification bar?

Tags: android, notifications, adb

Can someone tell me if there is a way to get the complete list of items currently being displayed in the notification bar?  I'm trying to write an interface that will trigger notifications to my PC based on the particular app giving the notification.

My only hits for something similar using the adb cli tool is [Receiving push notifications using adb shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625736/receivng-push-notification-using-adb-shell-command) which appears to be trying to get the notification from a particular app.

Other references that I am finding are related to actual android programming and sending your own notifications to the bar.

---

For the sake of formatting, I'm repeating my comment to fRoStBiT who provided the resource in his answer.  The following cli provides the specific item:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys notification | egrep NotificationRecord | awk -F\| '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use

```
adb shell dumpsys notification
```

It shows detailed information about currently displayed notifications.

Comment: Thanks.  At present there isn't any notifications on the bar, but as you mentioned, a large detailed list.  Most likely that is the items that have permissions to use the bar.  I'll study the full information to try to identify what about the list will change to indicate there is an active notification on currently on the bar.

Comment: @L.D.James There is a sample of output of this command (from my device): http://pastebin.com/gc6Etd0r

Comment: My list looks link yours.  I'm trying to see what item in the list will actually indicate an item is on the device's notification bar.  My list, like you're is big... however currently there is just one item being displayed on the notification bar.  So I'm studying the details to see what is different between the entry that has an item on the notification bar as all the other entries.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm able to use this cli to have the notices: `adb shell dumpsys notification | egrep NotificationRecord | awk -F\| '{print $2}'`.  All the other information is invaluable for future task.

Comment: 'egrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 9):

```
adb shell dumpsys notification | grep ticker | cut -d= -f2
```

shows me a little description of the texts of the screen.
`tickerText` appears to be the name of the property which contains the text of the notifications

Comment: How to have the full text? It just displays a part of the text and then `...`

Answer (score 9):

On Android >= 6 for get notification extras use this command

```sh
adb shell dumpsys notification --noredact
```

the full notifications text you can see at the `extras` section:

```
      extras={
          android.title=String (Bring The Rain)
          android.reduced.images=Boolean (true)
          android.subText=null
          android.template=String (android.app.Notification$MediaStyle)
          toSingleLine=Boolean (false)
          android.text=String (Upon A Burning Body)
          android.appInfo=ApplicationInfo (ApplicationInfo{c8165e6 org.telegram.messenger})
          android.showWhen=Boolean (false)
          android.largeIcon=Icon (Icon(typ=BITMAP size=100x100))
          android.mediaSession=Token (android.media.session.MediaSession$Token@608a746)
          gameDndOn=Boolean (false)
          android.compactActions=int[] (3)
            [0] 0
            [1] 1
            [2] 2
      }
```

Comment: This is the only way to get notifications texts. This helped me a lot.